# Using URL Parameters in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, url-parameters, reportbuilder3.0

I was wondering if someone could direct how i can set a parameter value in an .rdl file created in report builder from the URL used to call it on the report server?  Basically i have a drop-down filter in the report that is populated from a dataset that i need to call when the filter page is loaded.  The ID that i need is included in the URL call to the report, and i want to pass that to the stored procedure to populate the drop-down filter, but can not seem to figure it out.

```
exec planningGoalsGets @iHHID, 0
```

I need to get/set the @iHHID parameter from the value passed into the URL.  Example of the URL is;

```
http://*********/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fClient360+Reports%2fGoals+Summary&ViewMode=Detail&iHHID=850802
```

as you can see the iHHID is appended to the URL, but i am not able to get that to execute and populate the stored procedure when using the url to access it.  If i was able to test this in Report Builder itself that would be even better but I couldn't figure that out.  The image below is the query parameter value for the dataset, not sure if that is declared wrong.....
[image]

Comment: Did you add a parameter to the actual report, outside of the dataset?

Comment: yes, i did, i declared it as a parameter, just as @iHHID, I thought that it would basically pick up the iHHID set in the URL and set the value to that, i don't declare any available or default values for it

Comment: So in the report data drawer at the main view, under the Parameters folder you have `@iHHID` listed?

Comment: Yea, i declared it as the first parameter since i then have a filter dependent on the results of a stored procedure call using that parameter, and then a third parameter that will be set from the selected value of that filter drop-down

Comment: Is your parameter Name and Prompt in Report Parameter Properties the same?